# Allowing user to enter non standard characters such as " or ' in JAVA

Tags: java, input

Ok, So I don't know what I'm missing and I've gone through my material and googled for hours.  What I'm trying to do is allow a user to input height and inches using integers and the respective " and '.

I appreciate your help with this:

```
 int height, weight;
 double bmi;

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.print("What is your height in ft/in. You can say for" +
                 " example 5'9\" :" );
 height = keyboard.nextInt();

 System.out.print("What is your weight in lb :");

 weight = keyboard.nextInt();

 bmi = weight *703 / (height*height);

 System.out.println("Your bmi is : " + bmi);
```

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: Obviously "nextInt()" would not take those characters... So try some other "next.."...

Comment: 5'9 is not "int"

Comment: `5'9` is not an `int`. It's not any number. If you want to allow input in feet and inches, you'll have to read it as text, i.e. `String`. But you can't calculate with those Strings, so you'll have to parse the input and convert it to inches.

Comment: Also assigning 0 as "height" value returns error.

Comment: Not possible to get any character with nextInt()

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own Height class like:

```
class Height {
   private int feet;
   private int inches;

   public Height(int feet, int inches) {
      this.feet = feet;
      this.inches = inches;
   }

   public void setfeet(int feet)
   {
      this.feet = feet;
   }
   public void setinches(int inches)
   {
      this.inches= inches;
   }
   public int getfeet()
   {
      return this.feet;
   }
   public int getinches()
   {
      return this.inches;
   }

}
```

Then in your main class, you can do like:

```
System.out.print("What is your height -> feet: );
feet = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("What is your height -> inches: );
inches= keyboard.nextInt();

Height height = new Height(feet,inches);
```